# Childrens book involving two orphans that travel to space and find a space station captain that takes them in

Tags: story-identification, space, childrens-novel

Two orphans are touring a rocket that is about to go into space and they are accidentally launched into space where they get rescued by a captain of a secret space station. They make friends with most of the crew. However, part of the crew tries to take over the station and in the process the station is damaged and crashes on the moon. They survive and manage to find a way back to Earth.

Comment: Can you tell us when you read this? And approximately how long of a book? Was this 10 pages? 90? 200? Children's books can vary a lot. :) And do you remember any cover details?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this is *[Mission to the Moon](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?826970)*, by Lester del Rey, from 1956.

From Goodreads:

> Jim Stanley, who had helped to build the first space station, was thrilled to return to it as a member of the crew selected to erect the ships which would fulfill Man's age-long dream to reach the Moon. A total effort was being made to surpass the progress achieved in outer space by an enemy Combine. It was believed that if this foreign group scored the initial landing and gained control of the cold planet, the world would be threatened.
>
> The desperate effort to forge ahead of the Combine suddenly turns into a race against death when a young, space-happy boy takes off alone for the Moon in an inadequate ship. Although hampered by accidents, false rumors, and conflicts on Earth below, the crew works with frantic haste and grim determination to get the ships underway and to the boy in time. Jim Stanley, as mechanic and pilot, contributes a major share in the task of construction and on the tense rescue journey.
>
> Here is a gripping account of pioneers in space by one of science fictions best known and most skillful writers. Jim Stanley's adventures on the first flight to the Moon make a lusty and exciting tale for all who love to envision man's ultimate conquest of space.